# Does any standard Python3 object have a get method that doesn't have positional arguments?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to use a barely documented feature of a poorly documented API. I have distilled the chunk of code that is giving me trouble down to this for simplicity:

```
def build_custom_args(args):
    custom_args = {}
        for key in args:
            custom_args.update(key.get())
        print(custom_args)
```

I can tell from the function that constructs `args` that it is a list. Problem is, a list of *what?* No matter what I put in the list, key.get() raises one exception of another.

For example, if I execute that code like so: `build_custom_args(['foo'])` then I get an understandable error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Or, try a dictionary: `build_custom_args([{'foo': 'bar'}])`, but the error is raised: `TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0`.

As best I can tell `args` is a list of some standard python objects - there is no indication that these are special objects with a custom `get()` method.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there some standard python object that has a `get()` method which takes no positional arguments? Is this a syntax of some older version of Python? Or have I found a bug in the API?

**Edit**
The accepted answer shows that I was mistaken believing that `args` had to be a python built-in.

Jack's answer is worth a look because it actually does solve the problem "what Python built-in could `args` be that would cause this function to not throw an error?"

Comment: Python is duck typed, so there could be more than one type that implements a `.get`, talk less custom classes. You could start by telling what exactly the function is supposed to do, with the args

Comment: Are there any standard python types that have a `.get` method which takes no positional arguments?

Comment: Is this a Tkinter-based application, by any chance?  StringVar, IntVar, etc. have a zero-arg ``get()`` method.

Comment: I suppose there is no need for me to be cryptic about the API I'm looking at, I just wanted the answer to be more generally applicable than very specific. The API I am looking at is https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python. To answer your question specifically, no searching the repo for tkinter I don't see anything. The specific file I'm working on is https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/helpers/mail/mail.py at about line 70

Comment: You have a [`Header`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/helpers/mail/mail.py#L213) or [`CustomArg`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/helpers/mail/mail.py#L267) instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I found this in the github link you have provided

```
class Email(object):
    # code... 

    def get(self):
```

Matter of fact, a lot of those classes have get methods.

Since Python is duck typed, there isn't really a way to determine what object is correct, but you're just building a dictionary, so shouldn't matter too much

Comment: And I found this: class `CustomArg(object): ... return custom_arg`. I got so caught up thinking the custom_arg was a standard python type that when searches for custom_arg didn't turn anything up, I got completely side tracked going down this rabbit hole. Thanks, this clearly lead me to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only class with a `get` [method that can take zero arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=get#queue.Queue.get) is a `Queue`.

Which in your example is probably a `Queue` of `dict`s

Comment: However, `Queue` is not a built-in, so OP should check the imports to see if `queue` module is imported.

Comment: `Queue` is part of Python, but you only need to import if you're creating a new `Queue`. The way the method is in the question would NOT require it to be imported in that file.

Comment: That said, I agree doing a grep for `queue` or `Queue` in the full project would almost certainly lead to if this is the correct answer or not...although if the method just _expects_ a `Queue` it would not require an import anywhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I did not mean "the imports of the file", but "the imports in the whole project".

Comment: Jack is certainly right, and +1 for actually answering the question that I asked and not digging into github to answer the question that I needed answering.